# Fetch API yields "TypeError: failed to fetch"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, fetch-api

I am on Chrome, and I see this bizarre error:

```
TypeError: failed to fetch
```

**(yes, that is the whole error message).**

Here is the code that generated the error:

```
fetch(logoUrl, {
    method: 'put',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg',
      //encode credentials as base64
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('cdt-deployer:xyz'),
    },
    body: imgFile // the file

  }).catch(function(err){
       // the error appears here
  })
```

what am I supposed to do? I have no idea what's wrong. I am simply trying to send a binary image file to another server (I cannot see the server logs).

Comment: Please post full error.

Comment: If you try in a different browser do you get the same error? Have you successfully done the PUT using some other client like curl or Postman or something?

Comment: @emil that is the full error dude. I stated that in the question.

Comment: Yes it works with cURL, so it is not a server issue, per se.

Comment: Did you check CORS?

Comment: It should be a same-origin request. I am currently testing on Firefox. Chrome is what gave me the error originally.

Comment: my only guess, is that the image might not be `image/jpeg`..it might be a gif or a png file

Comment: Is there anything exceptional about the logoUrl URL? It’s just a pathname I guess?

Comment: @AlexanderMills, can you let us know if the server reported a 5xx error?

Comment: To be clear: when you try it using curl or whatever, you’re also sending the image as the entity body, with a 'content-type: image/jpeg' header? (And as far as the possibility that the problem might be the image isn’t a jpeg image but instead a gif or png, even if that were the case I am pretty sure it wouldn’t be causing that TypeError to be thrown)

Comment: with curl I am using the --data-binary option to send the file

Comment: Also wonder if it might be choking on `imgFile`. You might consider updating your question to show how `imgFile` is getting set

Comment: image file should be a binary image file, uploaded via `<input>` tag (filechooser)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript "TypeError: cancelled" error when calling "fetch" on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55738408/javascript-typeerror-cancelled-error-when-calling-fetch-on-ios)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the [Fetch API documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch):

> A `fetch()` promise rejects with a `TypeError` when a network error is encountered, although this usually means a permissions issue or similar.

One of these may be possible causes of "network error":

- DNS problems
- the server at `logoUrl` is unavailable / erroneous
- Erroneous HTTP Headers causing server to ignore the request
- Browser aborted -- most likely due to navigation to another page before the fetch completes

Comment: What do you mean by logoUrl?

Comment: @KemalTezerDilsiz the code in the question was trying to fetch a resource at logoUrl. I presume it's the URL of the server.