# Javascript "TypeError: cancelled" error when calling "fetch" on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, sentry

I'm logging JS client errors using Sentry and there's a lot of `TypeError: cancelled` errors. It's only occurring on iOS. I can't find anything on Google. Is this a native Javascript error or something else? What does it mean?

[image]

I also get similar errors in other languages, such as `취소됨`, `Abgebrochen`, and `cancelado`. This tells me that the error isn't raised by my code.

Comment: I've seen the same in my Sentry setup and it's limited to iOS 12.2 and mobile Safari 12.1 so far.  No stack trace included, so it's very cryptic.  I'm not sure what the issue is and haven't seen anything come up in related search results.  "Cancelled" portion of error message leads me to believe this could possibly be related to either promises or fetching.

Comment: Are you maybe sending a CORS request to a site that doesn't allow CORS?

Comment: @Aplet123 it works fine for ~97% of users, including iOS users. Maybe it has something to do with jailbroken phones with adblockers, etc.

Comment: We faced the same issues in Sentry logs.
There is an CORS issue starting from IOS 11.
We solved an issue this way https://stackoverflow.com/a/52004250

Comment: @AntonAntonov Thanks for the link, CORS issues is a strong possibility, but my requests don't have any headers

Comment: How its look like your fetch function call?
Maybe it's help you when add this to the fetch options: `headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }`

Comment: If you have an iOS device that you know causes this error then setup fiddler and force that device to use your fiddler as a proxy. Be warned I've seen fiddler FIX the issue! This ended up being a massive clue it was a proxy issue on the user's side.

Answer (score 34):

Frustrating right?

Recently our team encountered this same error. Here is what was happening in our case. When the page loads, the refresh button changes to cross button, now if some api request is in progress during this page loading time and the user click this cross button, then iOS chrome/safari throws this error. For the same situation Firefox browser throws `TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource` and chrome browser throughs `TypeError: Failed to fetch`.

This is not really an issue which we should be worried about, and so we decided to make sentry ignore this error by using the ignoreErrors attribute of sentry.

```
Sentry.init({
  dsn: "sentry_dsn",
  ignoreErrors: [
    'TypeError: Failed to fetch',
    'TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.',
    'TypeError: cancelled'
  ],
});
```

**Note:**
Failed to fetch is also generated by CORS errors, please be mindful of that too.
Also we decided to ignore errors with statusCode in between 400 to 426 using the beforeSend callback of sentry.

We spent days trying to find this error. Hope this helps somebody.

Thank you

Also,
This was originally written here: https://forum.sentry.io/t/typeerror-failed-to-fetch-reported-over-and-overe/8447/2

Comment: Should `cancelled` be lowercase? Because this isn't working for me currently.

Comment: yes @FernandoRojo it should be lowercased

Comment: See also similar errors in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49343024/getting-typeerror-failed-to-fetch-when-the-request-hasnt-actually-failed/65599511#65599511

Comment: Wow, this is really helpful - also been scratching my head on this for days.

Comment: Noticed this error as I'm working on filtering out non-actionable errors in Sentry now as well. One interesting thing I'm seeing is that it seems that we get the same error in different locales/translations. For example, I see `cancelled` as the exception value, but I also see exception values for 'cancelado', 'anulowane',  'annulé', 'đã hủy', 'отменено' which all translate back to the string 'canceled` in English. There is not much additional detail in Sentry to filter out this error.

Answer (score 18):

According to the WHATWG standard: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsing-the-web.html#aborting-a-document-load, fetch requests will be cancelled when aborting the document (close or navigate away). Apparently browsers are behaving differently so I made a tool to test the browser behavior if that helps: https://request-cancellation-test.vercel.app ([code](https://github.com/shuding/request-cancellation-test)).

Here're the test results for common browsers:

| Field | Chrome 95 | Safari 14 | iOS Safari 14 | Firefox 94 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `.toString()` | `TypeError: Failed to fetch` | `TypeError: cancelled` | `TypeError: cancelled` | `TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.` |
| `.name` | `TypeError` | `TypeError` | `TypeError` | `TypeError` |
| `.message` | `Failed to fetch` | `cancelled` | `cancelled` | `NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.` |
| `.stack` | `TypeError: Failed to fetch at ...` |  |  |  |

Answer (score 6):

If you are using the `fetch` API, it could be a problem with `AbortController` and `AbortSignal` in iOS 11.1-12, which would only be firing when someone tries to abort a fetch request (which is why it wouldn't necessarily affect all iOS users, explaining the inconsistency).

To elaborate, iOS 11.1-12 defines `AbortController` and `AbortSignal` in the DOM, but they are a stub - [see here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=abortcontroller). So if you try to abort a fetch request in iOS in <= 12, the request will not abort and would likely throw some sort of error.

Given it is a `TypeError` rather than an `AbortError` it would seem likely that the issue is with the `AbortController` not being properly/fully defined.

**EDIT:**
Further reading also seems to indicate that failed `fetches` in iOS throw `TypeError` errors, even for things like blocked fetches. As mentioned above, the issue could be with any ad-blockers installed (say, on a jailbroken iPhone) or a `CORS` issue, and iOS would then throw `TypeError` - [Webkit BugZilla discussion](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=184560). As such, concentrating on the error type might lead you down the wrong path.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another possibility for idiots like myself who did this ...

```
<form action="blah">
   <button onClick="javascript:submitForm();">Do It</button>
</form>
```

```
function submitForm() {

  fetch('https://api.mailerlite.com/api/v2/groups/group_name/subscribers', options)
       .then(response => response.json())
       .then(response => console.log(response))
       .catch(err => console.error(err));
   }

}
```

This will give the dreaded TypeError: cancelled

It's because its breaking off the connection and trying to do the post of the actual form you defined  (which wasn't even going anywhere)

SOLUTION:

```
<form action="blah">
   <button onClick="javascript:submitForm(event);">Do It</button>
</form>
```

```
function submitForm(event) {

  event.preventDefault()

  fetch('https://api.mailerlite.com/api/v2/groups/group_name/subscribers', options)
       .then(response => response.json())
       .then(response => console.log(response))
       .catch(err => console.error(err));
   }

}
```

This passes the event thru to the function where you can cancel the Form submission (using preventDefault) and then get on with your fetch.

Very simple stuff, but very easy to forget and have you pulling your hair out, especially coupled with that *Fantastically Descriptive and Useful* error message.

Answer (score 0):

I had to email Sentry to get the error right here.

I turns out, I was sending errors in the `extra` field, which isn't accounted for by the `ignoreErrors` property. I solved it like so:

```
const ignoreErrors = [
      'TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.',
      'TypeError: cancelled',
      'TypeError: Cancelled',
      'message: cancelled',
      'cancelled',
]

Sentry.init({
    async beforeSend(event) {
      // this is using typescript, but change it as you need
      const message = (event?.extra as
        | undefined
        | {
            error?: { message?: string }
          })?.error?.message?.toLowerCase()

      if (message && ignoreErrors.includes(message)) {
        return null // don't send
      }
      return event
    },
    ignoreErrors,
})
```

Comment: Do you know, what causes 'message: cancelled' and 'cancelled'? Are you confident that they can be ignored?

Comment: It's been a while, so I wish I had a better answer. But I *think* it's just due to network issues and can be ignored. I would do some research on it though.