# How to fix 'TypeError: Failed to fetch'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch-api

I'm getting a `TypeError: Failed to fetch` error when I attempt to send a post request using `fetch` on the front-end and an express route on the back-end.

I'm able to successfully create the new user in the db, but when attempting to obtain that new user data through the fetch promise, that's when the error is being thrown.

**app.js**

```
function createNewUser() {
  let formUsername = document.getElementById('signup-username').value;
  let formEmail = document.getElementById('signup-email').value;
  let formPassword = document.getElementById('signup-password').value;
  let url = "/users";
  let newUserData = {
    username: formUsername,
    email: formEmail,
    password: formPassword
  }

  fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
    credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
    referrer: 'no-referrer',
    body: JSON.stringify(newUserData),
  }).then(res => res.json())
  .then(response => console.log('Success: ', JSON.stringify(response)))
  .catch(error => console.error('Error: ', error));
}
```

**users.js**

```
router.post('/users', function(req, res) {
   User.create(req.body)
   .then(function(user) {
      res.json({
         user: user
      })
   }
});
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const auth = require('./auth');
const router = require('./routes/routes.js');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(router);

app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE" // what matters here is that OPTIONS is present
  );
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin");
  next();
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("Listening on port 3000");
});
```

I need to get that user object back in order to access its data.

**Edit:**
So, I've figured out that the issue has to do with how the request is submitted on the front-end. If I create the following function and then call it when `app.js` is loaded, then everything works:

```
function createNewUserTest() {
  let formUsername = 'dd';
  let formEmail = 'd@d.com';
  let formPassword = 'secrete';
  let url = "/api/users";
  let newUserData = {
    username: formUsername,
    email: formEmail,
    password: formPassword
  }
  fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    cache: 'no-cache',
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(newUserData),
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(response => console.log('Success: ', response))
  .catch(error => console.error('Error: ', error));
}

createNewUserTest();
```

But, if I try to call this function either through `onsubmit` in the form or `onclick` on the button in the html, or if I use an event listener (see below, which is in `app.js`), then I get the `TypeError: Failed to fetch` error:

```
let signupSubmitButton = document.getElementById('signup-submit');
signupSubmitButton.addEventListener('click', createNewUserTest);
```

This is even more baffling to me. I'm required to use Vanilla JS and I need to create the user through a form submission, but not sure what I need to adjust here.

**Solution**
Foiled by the `event.preventDefault()` again. This was all I needed.

```
let signupForm = document.getElementById('signup-form');
signupForm.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let formUsername = document.getElementById('signup-username').value;
  let formEmail = document.getElementById('signup-email').value;
  let formPassword = document.getElementById('signup-password').value;
  let url = "/api/users";
  let newUserData = {
    username: formUsername,
    email: formEmail,
    password: formPassword
  }
  fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    cache: 'no-cache',
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(newUserData),
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(response => console.log('Success: ', response))
  .catch(error => console.error('Error: ', error));
});
```

Comment: You don't need CORS for a same origin request... I imagine that's why it's throwing, considering your server won't respond with CORS headers.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Thank you for the response! Tried removing `mode: 'cors'` and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: "*Access-Control-Origin*", correctly named [Access-Control-*Allow*-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin), is a **response** header that is supposed to be sent from the server to the client, not the other way round.

Comment: @Bergi I added my `server.js` code to my initial request. I also removed the CORS property, as well as removing `"Access-Control-Origin"` from my `headers` object, but still getting the same error.

Comment: Hm, the updated code looks like it should work. On what domain(s) are you trying to run this? And what do the devtools say about the network requests?

Comment: @Bergi It looks like the request is failing (`users` is in red in devtools). Here is what is showing up under the `Headers` tab (nothing is displaying under the `Response` tab):

General
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/api/users
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Request Headers

Provisional headers are shown
Content-Type: application/json
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/no-referrer
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36

Comment: @Bergi And it's odd that, when I test through Postman (`Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`), I get a successful response. I tried changing `application/json` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and that didn't work either. Same exact data under the Network tab, save the updated `Content-Type`.

Comment: And what is the domain on which the script is running on, is it `localhost:3000` as well?

Comment: You should [post an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) with your solution.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, the domain is `localhost:3000`. Thanks for the tip on posting an answer, as well as all your responses!

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55738408/javascript-typeerror-cancelled-error-when-calling-fetch-on-ios

Answer (score 20):

The issue was that the page was reloading, which kept me from getting the data back in time. The solution was to simply add `event.preventDefault()` inside the listener.

**app.js**

```
let signupForm = document.getElementById('signup-form');
signupForm.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let formUsername = document.getElementById('signup-username').value;
  let formEmail = document.getElementById('signup-email').value;
  let formPassword = document.getElementById('signup-password').value;
  let url = "/api/users";
  let newUserData = {
    username: formUsername,
    email: formEmail,
    password: formPassword
  }
  fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    cache: 'no-cache',
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(newUserData),
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(response => console.log('Success: ', response))
  .catch(error => console.error('Error: ', error));
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed!

Comment: A very difficult error to pin down! Thank you!!

Comment: Avoid comments like +1... Yeah, whatever. +1 Dude! btw, you can accept your answer.

Comment: this totally blew my mind, everywhere on the internet it kept saying the error is about the CORS and preventDefault() is what we needed.

Answer (score 9):

The question is about "TypeError failed to fetch". The wording of the message sends one in the direction of network/server/CORS type issues as explored in other answers, but there is one cause I have discovered that is completely different.

I had this problem and took it at face value for some time, especially puzzled because it was provoked by my page POSTing in Chrome but not in Firefox.

It was only after I discovered chrome://net-internals/#events and saw that my request suffered from 'delegate_blocked_by = "Opening Files"' that I finally had a clue.

My request was POSTing a file uploaded from the user's computer via a file input element. This file happened to be a file open in Excel. Although it POSTed fine from Firefox, it was only when closed that it could be posted in Chrome.

Users of your web application need to be advised about this potential issue, and web developers should also be aware that "TypeError failed to fetch" can sometimes mean "TypeError didn't get as far as trying to fetch"

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to CORS problems it's very often because the server doesn't know how to handle it properly. Basically every time you include a header like `access-control-origin` to your request it will instigate OPTIONS preflight request as well and if your server is not expecting that it will throw an error, because it was expecting a POST only requests.

In other words - try again without the `"Access-Control-Origin": "*"` part and see if it works or just try patching it on the server with something like this:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE" // what matters here is that OPTIONS is present
  );
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization");
  next();
});
```

Comment: I added this block to my server.js file (from which I'm running `node server.js`), and even added `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to the last `res.setHeader` method, but still getting the same error. Makes me wonder if I have something going on with my `server.js` file, so I'm adding that to my initial request.

Comment: Now that i see you've updated your code with server.js file i think i know what's the problem. You've initialized all your routes (app.use(router)) before the part when you setHeaders. In Node the request goes from top to bottom of your file, so even though you added that setHeaders part it's already too late, because the request already went through the routes without any headers set on server. Try moving your routes after you set headers and see if that works.

Comment: Tried that as well, but no luck. I think there must be something about the response from the back-end. I noted it in the comments above, but I'm able to perform a successful GET request to a controller set up similarly, and I'm even able to get a successful response from a POST request through Postman. Firefox is showing a `304 Not Modified` error. I dug into that a little and I'm not sure why that's what I'm getting. Also just tried clearing cache and that didn't do it either.