# Failed to fetch?

Tags: javascript, input, fetch-api, weather-api

```
const weatherKey = '********';
const weatherURL = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather'

//Page Elements
let input = document.querySelector("#input");
const button = document.querySelector('#submit');
const destination = document.querySelector('#destination');

//Fetch
const getWeather = async () => {
    try {
        console.log(input.value);
        const apiURL = `${weatherURL}?&q=${input.value}&APPID=${weatherKey}`;
        console.log(apiURL);
        const response = await fetch(apiURL);
        if (response.ok) {
            const jsonResponse = await response.json();
            console.log(jsonResponse);
            return jsonResponse;
        } else {
            console.log("request failed!");
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

const renderWeather = (data) => {
    document.querySelector("#weather-degrees").innerHTML = data.main.temp;
}

const executeSearch = () => {
    getWeather().then(data => renderWeather(data));
}

button.addEventListener('click', executeSearch);
```

How come when I try to type something in the textbox and submit nothing logs and changes to my HTML. But when I have to click to see the preserve logs I see this. [image: Preserve Logs]

When I copy and paste the link, I can see the JSON file. Any idea what's wrong with my fetch?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56892082/how-to-fix-typeerror-failed-to-fetch

Comment: Consult the browser console. Could be the CORS problem.

Comment: Oh I looked at that link and tried event.preventDefault() and it worked! Thanks!

Comment: So, does this answer your question? [How to fix 'TypeError: Failed to fetch'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56892082/how-to-fix-typeerror-failed-to-fetch)

Comment: Yes, yes it did thank you.