# Cannot fetch from console, but can GET from address bar

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, fetch

I'm setting up a Rails API and cannot fetch from the console, even though I can retrieve data through the address bar.  In the console, I keep getting an error:

`TypeError: Failed to fetch at <anonymous>:1:1`

When I make the HTTP request from the address bar, I'm am able to retrieve the data with no problem.  I am using a serializer, and it is working correctly

Here is my fetch GET request:

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users')
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => console.log)
```

Here is the response:

```
Promise {<pending>}
[[Prototype]]: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "rejected"
[[PromiseResult]]: TypeError: Failed to fetch at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Here is my index action:

```
def index
   users = User.all
   render json: UserSerializer.new(users)
end
```

Here are my routes:

```
namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
        resources :users, only: [:index, :create]
        post '/login', to: 'auth#create'
        get '/profile', to: 'users#profile'
    end
  end
```

Here is my serializer:

```
class UserSerializer
  include FastJsonapi::ObjectSerializer
  attributes :username, :email, :password, :role
end
```

When I issue the same GET request from the address bar, I get the correct response:

```
// 20211108121639
// http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users

{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "type": "user",
      "attributes": {
        "username": "mlgvla",
        "email": "monica@test.com",
        "password": null,
        "role": "student"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I've tried changing the port to 3001, with exactly the same result.  I have some vague memory of this weirdness happening before a long time ago, but I forgot the reason why this happens.

Thanks for any guidance and wisdom about solving this issue.  Obviously, I can't set up my front-end until I know I can do a GET or POST using fetch!

Comment: When I search for "TypeError: Failed to fetch" I find the following match [How to fix 'TypeError: Failed to fetch'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56892082/how-to-fix-typeerror-failed-to-fetch) Which suggests that the fetch request is terminated due to a page change that is not prevented (when clicking a link or submitting a form). Are you doing something similar? If not, what does your server log say? Does the request reach the server? Is the server response successful?

Comment: Very good point - the fetch request is not reaching the server, at least when I'm observing the terminal the server is open in and I see no activity.  Yet the server is responsive when I put the request through the address bar.  I remember that I used to be able to send a fetch through the console.  Why is it not working now?

Comment: When are you firing the `fetch()` request? Is it on "submit" or link "click" event? If so, did you forget to call `event.preventDefault()`? If you don't prevent the default event action, a new page will be loaded before `fetch()` can send out its request.

Comment: I'm just trying the request from the console right now.  I haven't set up my front end yet.  How come I can't test it from the console?

Comment: You can paste the following in the console: `fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users').then(response => response.json()).then(users => console.log(users)).catch(error => console.error(error))`

Comment: So what do you see in the network panel?

Comment: LOL - That code worked!  It hit the server.  Why didn't my code hit the server?

Comment: I did try closing and opening the browser several times.  I pasted the exact code I originally used and it worked.  I wish I knew why the console is so mercurial!

Comment: Thanks for your help - I still would like to know why it didn't work the first time around.    Now let's see if I can do a POST request!

Comment: I think I figured out why.  It all depends on the page you are running the console off of, I think.  If the page has any previous TypeErrors, then the fetch won't work.  If the page is clean, then it works perfectly.

Comment: I don't think `.then(data => console.log)` does what you think it does.

Comment: ^ It's either `.then(data => console.log(data))` or `.then(console.log)` unless your intent is to ignore the parameter and return the `console.log` function as promise result.

Comment: Yes - I had a typo there - I pasted some early code.  Thx!

Answer (score 0):

That can be related to CORS security. It seems to me that you can't make a call directly to the back-end in this way. It works when you type the URL directly because it is handled by Rails

Try this gem, it should help you : [RACK CORS GEM](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors)

bundle install

And then add in **config/initializers/cors.rb** :

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', headers: :any, methods: [:get, :post, :patch, :put]
  end
end
```

For more security, you should restrict origins :-)

Comment: Thanks - I definitely already had Rack CORS configured as you have above.  I think the issue was running the fetch from the console from a page that loaded with TypeErrors.  When I ran the fetch from a page that had no TypeErrors, the fetch ran perfectly!  Go figure.